# Horizontal navigation in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I made a website with an horizontal navigation, simple menus with horizontal sliders. My problem is that in IE, on the element click, the slider works (horizontaly) but IE jump to the anchor verticaly.

The problem doesn't appear on the first item of the menu. Also it's not in the main navigation menu but in submenus.

You can see my problem here : http://matpreau.fr/test_limo/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the presence of anchors like `href="#cars"` on links. Try to replace with some anchor that not exists as ID of some element in the page (like `href="#null"`), or replace with `href="javascript:void(0)"`.